# Making Complex Android XML Drawables

Tags: android, xml, android-drawable, xml-drawable

How powerful are android XML based drawables?

I'm really wondering if it is possible to replace semi-complex bitmap assets, such as the following arrow icons, using only xml shapes.

[image]

So far I haven't seen many good example of anything other than basic shapes. I know `<layer-list>` can be used to combine shapes, but I've had a difficult time working with them. Particularly, relative sizing and offsets of shapes with `<layer-list>` does not seem to work well.

Comment: I think you can use 9-patch for that, will be less painful

Comment: Yes, you can, but **it's a pain in the ass**. But you could use **SVG** files (you'll need a 3rd party library, like [android-svg](https://code.google.com/p/androidsvg/)), instead. Or you can use [Unicode](http://unicode-table.com/en/) **characters**, since TTF fonts are vectorial, by definition. **Not all glyphs** are supported by the Android standard font, so you might want to use a free specialized **icon font**, such as [FontAwesome](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can, but **it's a pain in the ass**.

But you could use **SVG** files (you'll need a 3rd party library, like [android-svg](https://code.google.com/p/androidsvg/)), instead.

Or you can use [Unicode](http://unicode-table.com/en/) **characters**, since TTF fonts are vectorial, by definition.
**Not all glyphs** are supported by the Android standard font, so you might want to use a free specialized **icon font**, such as [FontAwesome](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/)

**[EDIT]**

Mark asked for it, so...

OK, This guy shows a tricky way to do arrow shapes via XML:
http://looksok.wordpress.com/2013/08/24/android-triangle-arrow-defined-as-an-xml-shape/

**[EDIT 2]**

For future memory (OK, for myself):

These are the keywords I entered in Google:
`android arrow xml drawables`
and (as a secondary search):
`android triangular xml drawables`

In case the first example isn't enough.

Comment: "Yes, you can" -- OK, I'll bite. How? Got an example?

Comment: Well, by using layer lists (layers of primitive items) and  transformations, such as rotations. I'll dig a bit, since I don't use this painful method. Then will give you some example (I think I saw something today)

Comment: @CommonsWare: Mark, I updated my answer with an example. Want more? Google! ;)

Answer (score 3):

As you mentioned positioning and sizing the shapes is the tragedy of that subject.

Alternatively you can use this library:
https://github.com/JoanZapata/android-iconify

It's using FontAwesome so you have all the flexibility of fonts...

Comment: Great resource. +1 for sharing.